# MySQL query to show salary depending on department

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with a peculiar problem. I have tried almost everything that I know.
The table contains the following details:

```
+--------+---------+--------+----------+
| emp_id | dept_no | salary | emp_name |
+--------+---------+--------+----------+
|      1 | c1      |  12300 | Rajesh   |
|      2 | c2      |  45123 | Arvind   |
|      3 | c3      |  12345 | Ravi     |
+--------+---------+--------+----------+
```

The expected output is like this :

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Dept_no | DeptC1 | Deptc2 | DeptC3 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| c1      |  12300 |      0 |      0 |
| c2      |      0 |  45123 |      0 |
| c3      |      0 |      0 |  12345 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am really stuck with this problem and have no idea how to solve this. I was trying to solve this with left outer joins but was not able to do it.

Comment: This is the most ridiculous, pointless expected output I have ever seen

Comment: why do you need this kind of output?

Comment: It might seem pointless but this is what's required. Can this be done? if yes then how? please suggest

Comment: that is so ineffective, because if you have 100 depts, then you have to make 100 columns too. isn't it?

Comment: @bprayudha yes you are right. In my scenario there was a fixed number of depts. only 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Dept_no,
       if(Dept_no='C1',salary,0) as Dept_noC1,
       if(Dept_no='C2',salary,0) as Dept_noC2,
       if(Dept_no='C3',salary,0) as Dept_noC3
From Emp
Group by Dept_no;
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c45fdd/3)

Output:

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Dept_no | DeptC1 | Deptc2 | DeptC3 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| c1      |  12300 |      0 |      0 |
| c2      |      0 |  45123 |      0 |
| c3      |      0 |      0 |  12345 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Is there any query that will work where we dont have a fixed number of department_no?

Comment: I think for that you have to go for dynamic queries